# Looking for a way to save 1 time variable in session storage

Tags: javascript, datetime, session-storage

I am looking for a way to save a getTime() value in sessionStorage even after reloading the page. This is to calculate some sort of elapsed time using Session Storage.

Is there anyone who has an idea of how to do this?

```
const date = new Date();

let time = date.toTimeString();
let newTime = date.toTimeString();

sessionStorage.setItem('startTime', time);
sessionStorage.setItem('newTime', newTime);
```

This is what I have right now, I am just looking for a a way to "permanently" save the startTime session key.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to save something longer than a session, you need to look at cookies

Comment: Session storage is cleared when the tab is closed. If you want 'permanent' you should use localStorage

Comment: I think I explained the question a little poorly....sorry

I mean I need to make it like the time value of "startTime" does not update and stays the same on page reload. To be able to calculate the difference between "startTime" and "newTime"